# Is their some kind of error handler for Spring @TransactionalEventListener

Tags: spring, error-handling, event-listener

Since recently I've been testing the use of the new `@TransactionalEventListener` from Spring.
But I can't find a nice way to handle error that could be thrown in the event listener method. 
By the way for what I've tested the `@EventListener` annotation doesn't have the same behavior : the `RunTimeException` is thrown as expected.

For example I would like to avoid write the try catch to be able to know about the error :

```
@Component
public class PairingEventListener {

    ...

    @TransactionalEventListener
    @Transactional
    public void onPairingSuccessEvent(PairingSuccessEvent event) {
      try {
        // some code here that could throws runtime error
      } catch (Exception e) {
          logger.error(e);
      }
    }
}
```

Does anyone know if there a way to achieve something equivalent to `JmsErrorHandler` but with Spring `ApplicationEvent`?

```
@Autowired
DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory jmsListenerContainerFactory;

...

jmsListenerContainerFactory.setErrorHandler(new JmsErrorHandler());
```

Thanks !